# Age of King Ahaziah

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, melachim-kings-book-of, book-of-chronicles, contradiction

Hey I'm here to ask about the supposed contradiction in Kings and Chronicles, what was Ahaziah's age? It definitly cannot be 40+ since he'd be as old/older then his father, hence the verse which is about 40 must be false or a mistranslation, so how do we reconcile this? Rashi's pirush, or Malbim are not of much use and complicated to understand.
Is there a way for Ahaziah to live until he's 40 to be crowned again? After his father's death? As David Kimchi proposed?

Sources :
II chronicles 22:2 vs II Kings 8:26

Comment: Why is being complicated to understand a disqualification? Lots of things in life are complicated and true.

Comment: Hi @KaijixPapa and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I don't understand why you are disregarding Rashi or the Malbim when they spell it out?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking at the [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.22.2?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_II_Chronicles.22.2.1&lang2=bi) at Divrei HaYamim II 22:2 which is perhaps worded in a more technical manner as it jumps straight into the problem without framing it accordingly, and given the fact that there is no Rashi on the verse in Malachim II 8:26, **are you aware that there is a Rashi later on [Melachim II 9:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_II_Kings.9.29.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which perhaps says it over in a more simplified way**:

He starts off by showing the evident problem:

> ...Here it states, “Achazyohu was twenty-two years old when he became king,” but in Divrei Hayomim [it states], “He was forty-two years old when he reigned.” Yehorom, his father, lived for forty years, no more, as it is stated, concerning him, “He was thirty-two years old when he became king, and he reigned eight years [in Yerusholayim].” How then is it possible for a son to be two years older than his father?

Rashi therefore explains that it is a very simple technicality as per the Seder Olam and Tosefta:

> **Rather, twenty years before he was born, which is two years before his father was born, this decree was issued.** From the day that Asa took Omri’s daughter in marriage for Yehoshophot his son, a decree was issued upon the House of Dovid that it be destroyed with the House of Achov. And similarly it states, “And from God [it was decreed] for the ruination of Achazyohu, that he come to Yorom, etc.” Thus it is taught in [**Seder Olam**](https://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.17.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and in the [**Tosefta**](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Sotah.12.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) of [Maseches] Sotah.

Only issue is that Rashi points out there appears to be no reference anywhere in Tanach for this marriage, meaning it might be going on another marriage from which we can balance out the numbers:

> However, in all of Scripture, we do not find that Yehoshophot married Omri’s daughter. However, I did find in Divrei Hayomim, “And he intermarried with Achov.”
> Perhaps this [refers to] his sister whom he married. **He married her in the thirty-first year of Asa**, as it is stated, “In the thirty-first year of the reign of Asa, [King of Yehudah], Omri reigned [over Yisroel].” And we learned in Seder Olam that he reigned over the entire kingdom, for six years before then he reigned over half the people, and when Asa took his [Imri’s] daughter in marriage to [his son] Yehoshophot, Imri gained prestige, and they assassinated Tivni. **Proceed and calculate from the thirty-first year of Asa until Achazyohu’s death and you will find them to be forty-two [years]**.

Comment: I hope breaking it into bitesize pieces makes it more easy to understand?

Comment: One, question, this explains it but the verse doesn't imply that, the verse says Ahaziah was 42 not the decree, is there another instance in the hebrew of such happening or a similar thing in the tanakh?

Comment: @KaijixPapa There are many other cases of discrepancies being explained similarly in Melachim.

Comment: I be am challenging this view at all, but I’m really having difficulty understanding it. Perhaps a more simplified explanation, for the more textually challenged?

Answer (score -1):

Scholars of textual criticism consider the difference to be a copyist's error transcribing 4 instead of 2 in the first number of the age when they began to reign, now which side they erred no one knows for sure. Attempts to explain this by explanations that are not found in the scriptures have no scientific validity and are restricted to the theological sphere, it seems to me that you want an exact and technical explanation and this is the most accurate there is, as well as other inconsistencies as in reign of Jeconiah, began to reign at 8 or 18 years old? Here the same explanation fits, only this time they omitted or added the 1, which side of the books is the question. Only an addendum, some Greek and Syriac versions of 2 Chronicles 22:2 finds the age of 22 when he began to reign, only the Masoretic text which the modern translations are based on does not contain this version.

Comment: 1. Study of scripture is never "scientific". 2. This is the Judaism SE and by definition theological. 3. The presupposition in Jewish study of these books is that they were divinely inspired and do not always mean what they appear to mean on the surface. That is a matter of historical belief. 4. A method of study that removes the books from their historical context and understanding is the opposite of scientific.

Comment: It is scientific because it is registered in something palpable and in which there are several versions that can be compared and based on judging the value of these testimonies, the papyri say, for example the oldest version of the Tanach is the Septuagint, this means that it originated from greek? No way. How do we know not? Is it because of the Letter of Aristeas? Textual style can explain up to the time it was written, book of Daniel has parts in Aramaic and some expressions from Hellenistic times and so on.

Comment: Science means testable hypotheses with predictable outcomes. In terms of history, all you get is educated guesses.

Comment: Textual criticism is not history but forensic investigation. Its objective is not to deconstruct traditions, beliefs or cultures, but to reconstruct an accurate image of the time, circumstance in which they were written. Whoever evaluates textual criticism is making a historical evaluation, subject to various strands and currents of thought, but the empirical evidence is indisputable. Many Jews accept the claims of textual critics without feeling outraged or disrespected, only the most orthodox still remain unshaken that it was Moses who wrote the Torah and so on.

Comment: No disrespect, but it is all just educated guesses, usually from a mindset that starts by *dismissing* the claims of history. Your second sentence is just drinking the kool-aid. Most textual critics do an execrable job of looking at the text from the lens of archaeology and similar documents in history. See "On the Reliability of the Old Testament" by Kenneth A. Kitchen.

Comment: Does that mean then that the best explanation for these inconsistency in Ahaziah age is a midrash and any scribal errors are absurd in the light of tradition? Know that the first textual critics came out of the religious bosom.

Comment: 1. Why not a midrash? Seder Olam is a medrash specifically devoted to history and matters of chronology. 2. There is an extensive masoretic tradition regarding the proper spelling and punctuation of the Bible. Gross errors of the sort you describe would be unlikely to survive. 3. If by religious you mean German Protestants, you are right. They followed Martin Luther, who was a vicious anti-Semite.

Comment: There are and are texts where they deliberately changed the meaning of a word for theological reason as in Job 2:9, the Hebrew text brings the expression bless and not curse, they are similar words, they found it absurd to let curse in connection with God. Another is Judges 18:30 transcribed Jonathan, son of Gershom, son of Manasseh, who lived centuries later and Manasseh for Moses changes little, they found it absurd descendants of Moses making a graven image, this is proof that the book is post-exilic because it brings characters that didn't even exist at the time.

Comment: 1. Bless is just a euphemism. Context is clear it means curse. 2. According to Rabbis it is the descendant of Moses. There is no reason to assume it means Manasseh of later generations, it could be anyone named Manasseh. We also find that name as a son of Joseph.

Comment: The Septuagint behind “son of Moses”, was a religious copyist and later felt constrained to transcribe a passage correlating the figure of Moses with the making of images through his descendants. The irregular Masoretic sign in the middle of the name was purposeful, not meant to be there, pure corruption of the text. As for Job, no matter what it was, it proves that depending on the context it changes by religious taboo like not putting “curse and God” at the same time, Job 1:5 proves this, Job sacrificed because he thought his children had cursed God but in the text it says bless

Comment: There are very many Masoretic signs like that throughout the Bible. If it was meant to be a corruption of the text, it would have been normally written, not formalized in the Masorah. This is so obvious it is weird that you argue the opposite. The use of euphemism is normal in Hebrew. You have no basis to assume this was a later corruption of the text, rather than a euphemism by the text's original author.

Comment: Massretic text is the standard Jewish religious text, it does not mean the most faithful because it is not the oldest, given the 11th century, what exists is, the Septuagint renders Judges 18:30 as the son of Moses and not of Manasseh, this proves that the Hebrew text current at the time of translation had not undergone scribal correction. As for Job, euphemism is the religious explanation of the passage in Job 2:9. but the true meaning is given in Job 1:5, no one makes a sacrifice for understatement that his sons were actually blessing God

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/70769/if-the-lxx-version-of-judges-1830-states-%CE%9C%CF%89%CF%85%CF%83%E1%BF%86-moses-why-would-new-testame

Comment: The earliest references to the Masoretic tradition go back to the time of Ezra. The one most in  use is codified in the eleventh century, but the "nun" in Manasseh is already mentioned in Talmud, which is fifth century.

Comment: As the reference to the written Talmud is from the 5th century, it is not possible to trust that the suspended letter was always present in the oldest documents, the Septuagint and the Peshitta do not bring this expression son of Manasseh, so it was not careless of those who translated, they knew perfectly well that in Judges 18:30 it was Moses and not Manasseh, were faithful to the text. Masoretic text carries religious traditions, not just textual accuracy and I don't see problems with that, so much so that they assume it's Moses and explain why they want it to read like that.

Comment: The original Septuagint was only on the Pentateuch, and was lost in antiquity. What you call Septuagint is just a generic term for Greek translations. They have no special authority. See ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suC65nh-9rI ). Anyways you admit that this is not an example of a careless scribal error. Neither is the case of Job. You are using arguments of what you consider scribal fixes to text to explain careless non-fixes to text in answering OP's question.

Comment: At no time did I say that the Septuagint is superior to the Hebrew text, in this specific passage of Judges 18:30 it is evident that there was theological influence not to correlate Moses with idolatry through textual artifice since there is no identifiable Gerson son of Manasseh and it is very difficult to suppose that the author of Judges, who by tradition is Samuel, was aware of a future idolatrous Manasseh and transcribed it like this and the scribes came faithfully copying it, there would already be a question of inspiration of the text and there is no discussion about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139990/discussion-between-thales-and-n-t).

Comment: Like I said in the beginning, if you assume that the Bible is written with divine inspiration (as most users of this site do, and the Talmud definitely did), then it is very reasonable. You clearly are operating from the framework of the Biblical Criticism crowd, which like any framework, is built on the assumption that it is valid, and opposing frameworks are not. If you want to write answers that are useful on this SE, you must learn to operate from within its framework. Otherwise, just go to Biblical Hermeneutics, and where you can keep reducing divine documents to historical records.

Comment: But can the site only be accessed and interacted with by those who see the Bible as inspired? As far as I know the author of the question brought up a question of chronological inconsistency and not of Halachah subjects which I do not get involved in because it is not my area, textual criticism offers an explanation, in the same way that midrash offers, that is , I cannot use textual criticism to explain laws or something similar, but issues such as genealogy, chronology, etc.

Comment: Anyone can access the site, but most people who use it are interested in Jewish answers. Non-Jewish answers to biblical questions are not really on topic for a Judaism site.