# Another contradiction? How can numbers be different if it is divine? 1 + 1 = 2 always?

Tags: tanach

24And the king said to Aravnah, "No; for I will only buy it from you at a price; so that I will not offer to the Lord my God burnt-offerings [which I had received] for nothing." And David bought the threshing-floor and the oxen for fifty shekels of silver.

Shmuel II.24:24.

And David gave to Ornan for the place shekels of gold weighing six hundred.

Divrei Hayamim I 21:25.

fifty shekels of silver or shekels of gold weighing six hundred?

3rd contradiction
link to 2nd and 1st

[More contradictions in the torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136243/more-contradictions-in-the-torah)

[Contradiction in the torah? Please explain this. I have heard many times that a divine book can not contradict](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136236/contradiction-in-the-torah-please-explain-this-i-have-heard-many-times-that-a)

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.21.25?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_I_Chronicles.21.25.1&lang2=bi

Comment: Your first 2 "contradictions" have been proven to NOT be contradictions. It appears you are not following along with your own posts. The answer of this one is again simple. The first quoted verse speaks of the weight of shekels in silver, where as in Chronicles it speaks of the weight of the SAME amount of shekels but in gold. Fifty shekels, however the WEIGHT of it was converted to gold. It's like saying 10 dollars in pesos or NIS. Different economic value during the time, same amount of money

Comment: As stated before. The Jewish commentaries have addressed all of these. Please look at Sefaria first. And while we believe all of Tanach is Divinely influenced, Samuel, Kings, and Chronicles all had different human authors, with different angles and focuses. Thus, different verses may be "getting at" different lessons, and thus focusing on different aspects, using similar language. You think it's 1+1=2, but marriage therapists will tell you 1+1=1.

Comment: @shmosel That Rashi is briliant. It should be a conclusive proof that the SAME number of shekels (silver coins) only had the WEIGHT of gold when they were all combined for the sake of all tribes having a portion (a pure motive, like gold is pure)

Comment: Please don't come here to dump verses and links - write up your questions in plain English, independently of other questions you may have asked.

Comment: Something being divine does not make it automatically easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, Rashi says:

> How is this possible? He took FIFTY shekels from each tribe, totaling SIX HUNDRED shekels, so that all Israel should have a share in the altar.

Let it be known that the WEIGHT of the coins were only compared to as gold (a pure substance) when they were **COMBINED**. Why? Because the purity of each tribe contributing for the sake of God and His commandments is LOFTIER.

10 USD will be 36.57 NIS, or 9.11 Euros (at the time this is posted), it is different in "weight" compared to the economic value of the time and place, but it is the same amount of money.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this question and forgot about it... if you please edit the question (e.g. change a few words thaen change it back) so I can undo my downvote

Comment: @fartgeek you can do so yourself