# How do we reconcile the passages from 2 Samuel 10:18 which says David killed 700 Rechev with 1 Chronicles 19:18 which says David killed 7000 Rechev?

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, book-of-chronicles, contradiction

In [Shmuel](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Samuel.10.18?lang=bi) it says David killed 700 chariots, while in [Divrei HaYamim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.19.18?lang=bi) it says David killed 7000 chariots? It uses the exact same language. How do we reconcile this?

Comment: Radak suggests the 700 were רכב בחור

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Note another contradiction in the same verse: In Shmuel it's 40k horsemen and in DH it's 40k infantry soldiers. And a slight variant spelling of the Aramean general's name: Shovach vs Shofach.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136236/contradiction-in-the-torah-please-explain-this-i-have-heard-many-times-that-a/136248#136248